# How to handle bursts with Actors?

Tags: scala, concurrency, akka, actor

Suppose I have an actor, which handles `X` requests per second. It is ok in average but sometimes there are *bursts* and clients send `Y > X` requests per second. Suppose also that all requests have timeouts so they cannot wait in queue forever.

Assuming we program in Scala and `Akka` what are the best practices/design patterns to make the actor handle those bursts? Are there any code examples, which handle bursts?

Comment: What is throttling the actor to X requests per second?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as your machine can handle the increased load (i.e. has enough CPUs), then I would suggest pooling the `Actor` using a `Router`.  It sounds like from your example, a dynamically resizing router might be the best fit, but even a standard Round Robin or Smallest Mailbox might be enough.  Below is the link for the routers section from the Akka documentation.  I hope this helps.

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.1.2/scala/routing.html

You could also consider distributing the actor across multiple nodes, but that might be overkill for your scenario.  If you have interest in that approach, let me know and I can post more context on doing that.

Now as far as what to do when after you pool the actors but the system still is getting backlogged, that's really up to you, but here are a few options.  If you can handle the occasional increases in latency due to bursting, then do nothing.  The actors mailboxes will just get a little backed up but they will clear as soon as the burst eases off.  If not, then the question is how to handle incoming messages when the actors are backlogged.  If you want to fast fail in that situation and not accept the message you might want to look into using a bounded mailbox (http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.1.2/scala/dispatchers.html).  When the mailbox reaches it's size limit and can no longer queue messages, the caller will get a failure sending the message (I think).  Not awesome, but at least will lead to the system stabilizing faster.

I assume you are doing `ask (?)` (i.e. request/response), so when you do that, you get a `Future`.  That `Future` will time out (with an implicitly defined timeout value) if it does not receive a response in time, so during a burst, Futures attached to the calls into the backlogged actors will just start timing out; they will not be stuck there forever.

Comment: Thank you. I will be thinking about routers. Distributed (remote) actors are out of my scope. Now suppose the machine is overloaded and there is no more machines. How to handle bursts properly?

Comment: Added a little more info.  Hopefully this helps.  Let me know if not.

Comment: Here's an interesting article on throttling actors.  Thought it was relevant to this discussion.  http://letitcrash.com/post/28901663062/throttling-messages-in-akka-2