# How to guarantee response time of Actor?

Tags: scala, concurrency, akka, actor

This is a follow-up to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16252015/how-to-handle-bursts-with-actors):

Suppose I have an actor, which handles `X` requests per second. However sometimes there are bursts and clients send `Y > X` requests per seconds. Now I have to *guarantee* that a client receives a response (ether *success* or *timed out* status) within a given timeout.

Assuming I use Scala and Akka how would you suggest implement it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, a little code example to show the timeout handling:

```
import akka.actor._
import akka.util.Timeout
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import akka.pattern._
import scala.util._
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException

object TimeoutTest {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val sys = ActorSystem("test-system")
    implicit val timeout = Timeout(2 seconds)
    implicit val ec = sys.dispatcher
    val ref = sys.actorOf(Props[MyTestActor])

    val fut = ref ? "foo"
    fut onComplete{
      case Success(value) => println("Got success")
      case Failure(ex:TimeoutException) => println("Timed out")
      case Failure(ex) => println("Got other exception: " + ex.getMessage)
    }
  }
}

class MyTestActor extends Actor{
  def receive = {
    case _ =>
      Thread.sleep(3000)
      sender ! "bar"
  }
}
```

You can see in this example, I am specifying an `ask` timeout of 2 seconds and my actor is sleeping 3 seconds before responding.  In this scenario, I will always get the `Failure` wrapping a `TimeoutException`.  Now, timeout handling is not native to Scala's `Future` class, but fortunately, Akka added timeout support to their `ask` operation.  Under the hood, when you perform an `ask`, Akka creates two `Promises`; one that can be completed by the actor responding to the message, and another that gets completed by a timer task in a `HashedWheelTimer` class.  Then, Akka takes the `Futures` from those two `Promise` instances and combines them into one with `Future.firstCompletedOf` so the `Future` you get back from the `?` call can be completed by either a response from the actor that received the message or from a timeout, whatever happens first.

Answer (score 1):

It depends how you use the actor. If you are using 'ask' ( as in `actor ? msg`), you receive a future which times out after a specified time.

See http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/futures.html (Use With Actors)

You can add an onFailure hook to the future which allows you to send error response to the client if future times out.

Future api: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.concurrent.Future